# insert and delete in order statistic tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-trees

I am having trouble in understanding [order-statistics tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) .

**Definition :**
Every node in tree stores the number of descendants of itself .
Can you please explain the Algorithm or pseudocode how to **Insert** and **Delete** a node in the tree **when tree is to be balanced** .

Basically i want to find the rank of an element in the tree in **O(log N)** time complexity and nodes can be inserted and deleted in between querries .

P.S. I am able to understand the **rank(x)** operation .

Comment: I think it is better if you worked it out yourself. This is the best way to understand how it works. Try drawing up a tree and manually inserting and deleting elements, updating the tree accordingly. You should then be able to come up with pseudocode for **Insert** and **Delete**.

Answer (score 2):

The exact implementation of **Insert** and **Delete** depends on the underlying binary tree structure which is used, but the idea is that you maintain the *size* field throughout the operation. Consider for example the following **Insert** procedure, which always inserts its element as a new leaf:

**Insert(Tree, $x$)**

1. If Tree is empty, set Tree to be $x$, and return.
2. Let $r$ be the root of Tree, and Left, Right its children.
3. If $x < r$ then call Insert(Left, $x$), otherwise call Insert(Right, $x$).

Here is the updated algorithm, which maintains the size information:

**Insert(Tree, $x$)**

1. If Tree is empty, set Tree to be $x$ and *size*(Tree)=1, and return.
2. Increase *size*(Tree) by 1.
3. Let $r$ be the root of Tree, and Left, Right its children.
4. If $x < r$ then call Insert(Left, $x$), otherwise call Insert(Right, $x$).

This is the basic idea. You can take it from here.

Comment: yes , i knew this , but i am interested in **balanced** insert/delete , sorry i missed it in my question .  The step 2. you gave is not correct when rotations occour.

Comment: The same idea works even when rotations occur, you just have to be more careful. I'm sure you can work it out yourself.